# Tell When a UIPageViewController is Scrolling (for Parallax Scrolling of an Image)

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to make an effect similar to that found in the new Yahoo weather app. Basically, each page in the `UIPageViewController` has a background image, and when scrolling through the page view, the Image's location only scrolls about half the speed. How would I do that? I thought I could use some sort of Delegate Method in the `UIPageViewController` to get the current offset and then update the images like that. The only problem is that I cannot find anyway to tell if the `UIPageViewController` is being scrolled! Is there a method for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
for (UIView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
         [(UIScrollView *)view setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

this gives you access to all standard scroll view API methods.
And this is not using private Apple API's.

I added traversing through subviews, to 100% find the `UIPageViewController`'s inner scroll view
**WARNING**:
Be careful with **scrollview.contentOffset**. It resets as the controller scrolls to new pages

If you need persision `scrollview` offset tracking and stuff like that, it would be better to use a `UICollectionViewController` with cells sized as the collection view itself and paging enabled.

Comment: If Apple changes the architecture of their page view controller you're screwed.

Comment: @VanDuTran agreed, but until then, its all good, and seems like the best approach. I don't see an alternative

Comment: It wasn't the first subview for me, but the second one. This code did it: `if([self.pageVC.view.subviews[1] respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]){
        [self.pageVC.view.subviews[1] setDelegate:self];
    }`

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't give standard results for scrollview.contentOffset. It resets at each new page.

Comment: @Paul, well, looks like the alternative was stealing my answer.. :)

Comment: This is dangerous and at risk for crashes when Apple updates the API. UIPageViewController just doesn't work for this sort of thing. I finally just switched over to a UIScrollView.

Comment: Not agree. The only risk is to not find the scrollview since there is a check on the `UIScrollView` type. Btw, this solution is not elegant, the alternative is nicer.

Comment: It is not only about chnages by Apple, but you assigns the new delegate, so if the inner implementation of UIPageViewController uses it, you would break that.

Comment: Could do 
pageViewController.view.subviews.lazy.compactMap { $0 as? UIScrollView }.first?.delegate = self

Answer (score 15):

I would do this:

**Objective-C**

```
for (UIView *v in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView *)v).delegate = self;
    }
}
```

and implement this protocol

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

**Swift**

```
for view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews {
  if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
    scrollView.delegate = self
  }
}
```

and implement this protocol

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

Comment: Thank you for the Swift Code piece

Answer (score 4):

```
extension UIPageViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView? {

        return view.subviews.filter { $0 is UIScrollView }.first as? UIScrollView
    }
}
```

Using:

```
pageController.scrollView?.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it is *not* a UIPageViewController, but rather a paged UIScrollView. The UIScrollView *does* give you a constantly repeated delegate method that tracks what is happening as the scrolling takes place.

Alternatively, you *might* be able to access the paged UIScrollView that the UIPageViewController is secretly using, but you might break something, and I'm not sure how Apple would feel about it.

Comment: There must be a way to do this with a UIPageViewController. It just simplifies everything if I use it. The Yahoo App looks like it uses a UIPageViewController also. Is there a way to get the position onscreen from within the UIViewController's themselves?

Comment: Isn't a UIPageViewController basically just a fancy UIScrollView?

Comment: It may be simpler for you, but I assure you that with UIScrollView alone we were doing stuff like scroll-style UIPageViewController long before scroll-style UIPageViewController existed. There are entire WWDC videos devoted to explaining how to do it.

Comment: It is fancy but opaque. As I said, you can work your way down the view hierarchy and find the scroll view. But you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Is there a way I could put a scroll view on top and just read data from that?

Answer (score 3):

Use @Paul's snippet -

```
for (UIView *v in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
    ((UIScrollView *)v).delegate = self;
}
}
```

to implement this protocol : `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGPoint point = scrollView.contentOffset;

float percentComplete;
percentComplete = fabs(point.x - self.view.frame.size.width)/self.view.frame.size.width;
NSLog(@"percentComplete: %f", percentComplete);
}
```

This gives you the percentage completion of the scroll. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3 you could write it even shorter:

```
if let scrollView = self.pageViewController.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) as? UIScrollView {
    scrollView.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called parallax scrolling, you can find several libraries that can help you with that.

Edit: Matt is right this is not an answer, only a hint. Anyway let's complete it:

For animating a background image that lay behind your UIPageViewController you should use the delegate methods that it offer:

```
-[id<UIPageViewControllerDelegate> pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:]
-[id<UIPageViewControllerDelegate> pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:]
```

With these two methods you can calculate the percentage of the scrolling (you should store your controllers in your array to know at which controller you scrolled to and get the percentage)

Comment: How would you get the percentage from that?

Comment: You should get the position of the searched view controller with `-[NSArray indexOfObject:]` then you can do some basic math to get the percentage of that index respect of the `-[NSArray count]`

Comment: That isn't really what I want. Each view controller has its own UIImage inside of it. I need to control the position of the image pixel by pixel, and using a percentage like that would simply not work.

Comment: mm probably you can look into `-[UIPageViewController gestureRecognizers]` for a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and use its methods to know exactly (and legally) what is the current movement.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to change the delegate of the page view controller's scroll view: it can break its normal behaviour and/or not be supported later on.

Instead, you can:

1. Add a pan gesture to the page view controller's view:

   ```
   let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panRecognized(gesture:)))
   view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
   panGesture.delegate = self
   ```
2. Add the new function in order to know how the view is being scrolled.

   ```
   @objc func panRecognized(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
       // Do whatever you need with the gesture.translation(in: view)
   }
   ```
3. Declare your ViewController as `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.
4. Implement this function:

   ```
   func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       return true
   }
   ```

Comment: this causes a problem with swipe back if the page view controller is pushed on a navigation stack (swipe back will be recognised simultaneously with horizontal swiping in the page view controller)