# How to load data for next page using UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I got UIPageViewController working finally a few days ago. I am using different UITableViewControllers as the "pages". There is a slight problem that i have that i want to fix.

When i scroll, the view is empty until fetches the new data which i don't like. I would like the data to be loaded before scrolling so it goes swiftly. So the question is: If i can load the next page somehow before scrolling.

I thought of a way to "fix" this in an ugly way by calling the fetch function somewhere before and save the dictionary in  **NSUserDefaults** so when the view loads for the first time the data is already "loaded" and can be used.

Any other ideas of how this can be done the "right" way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to reload you next page data at

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers
```

It is a delegate method in `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`

Comment: I tried a simple NSLog to see if it is getting called when i scroll but it did not get called? I have other delegate methods working.

Comment: viewControllerBeforeViewController & viewControllerAfterViewController are datasource methods. willTransitionToViewControllers is a delegate method. Are you setting _pageVc.delegate = self or something

Comment: Thnx it got called. But i dont get what i can do to make the view to load as it loads before it gets presented so when it actually is time to  show the view it has already been loaded. Get it? Because what i can do using that delagate method is to call the PageContentViewController but thats not the  class that is going to be shown.

Answer (score -1):

You can use UIScrollView delegate for this. Set UIScrollViewDelegate in your viewDidLoad method to your controller and override scrollViewDidScroll method.

Comment: I am using UIPageViewController

Comment: UIPageViewController based on UIScrollView. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19066412/2852037