# iOS PageController with tabs

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement something similar to Instagram's Search view that (I'm guessing) uses a Page Controller with tabs and a small scroll bar to track the position.

[image: Instragram Search]

The tabs seem straight forward enough but what's the best way to implement the scroll bar? Is there anything built in or do I need to figure out how to track the position of the page controller and draw the line manually?

Comment: Do you want to move the line in the same amount as user scroll to other page? It is possible by calculating scroll offset of page and apply it the line proportionally.

Comment: Yeah that's right. So what would be the best way to track the position of the scroll offset?

Comment: Make some object to be UIPageViewContoller's scroll view delegate and implement scrollViewDidScroll. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268235/tell-when-a-uipageviewcontroller-is-scrolling-for-parallax-scrolling-of-an-imag